# No change to ListView when text is entered in filter TextField

Tags: javafx, textfield, fxml, predicate, observablelist

**EDIT** **---** Showed Object classes, added code inside initialize method, removed former filter method, and removed OnAction for TextField from FXML. **---**

My first attempts at trying to figure this out resulted in many Android problems, so here I am.

I made a simple GUI using JavaFX, Scenebuilder, and FXML. This GUI simulates the inventory of a plant shop, and can add to/remove from/display in/save to a file from an `ObservableList`. It is also supposed to filter objects based on partial `String`s entered by the user in a `TextField`.

This was simple in a former incarnation of this program, since it was all via command line; however, I've run into a new problem that I've never seen before.

Each object prints with a pseudo-random ID number with user-specified prefix (F for Flower, W for Weed, H for Herb, Fn for Fungus), the Name, Color, and boolean attributes such as "thorny", "scented", "edible", etc. Those are determined by Radio Buttons. For example, if the user enters all the values of a new Flower, it prints as: "ID: F-21, Name: Rose, Color: Red, Thorny? False, Scented? True"

Here is my initial ObservableList and FilteredList:

```
ObservableList<Plant> observablePlantList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<Plant> filteredList = new FilteredList<Plant>(observablePlantList);
```

Here is my Plant class and one subclass (there are 4 exactly the same) to show how they display in the list (booleans are Radio Buttons):

```
    public class Plant {
public String ID;
public String name;
public String color;
public boolean smell;
public boolean thorns;
public boolean edible;
public boolean poisonous;
public boolean flavor;
public boolean medicine;
public boolean seasonal;
public int idNum;

public Plant(String ID, int idNum, String name, String color, boolean smell, boolean thorns, boolean edible, boolean poisonous, boolean flavor, boolean medicine, boolean seasonal) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.idNum = randomID(idNum);
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.smell = false;
    this.thorns = false;
    this.edible = false;
    this.poisonous = false;
    this.flavor = false;
    this.medicine = false;
    this.seasonal = false;
}

public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}
public void setID(String ID) {this.ID = ID;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public String getID() {return ID;}
public String getName() {return name;}

public int randomID(int idNum) {
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    idNum = randomNum.nextInt(50);
    return idNum;
}

public String toString() {

    return "ID: " + this.ID + "-" + this.idNum + ", Name: " + this.name + ", Color: " + this.color;
}

}
```

Subclass

```
    public class Flower extends Plant {

public Flower(String ID, int idNum, String name, String color, boolean smell, boolean thorns, boolean edible, boolean poisonous, boolean flavor, boolean medicine, boolean seasonal) {

    super(ID, idNum, name, color, smell, thorns, edible, poisonous, flavor, medicine, seasonal);
}
public void setSmell(boolean smell) {
    this.smell = smell;
}
public void setThorns(boolean thorns) {
    this.thorns = thorns;
}
public String toString() {

    return super.toString() + ", Scent? " + this.smell + ", Thorns? " + this.thorns;
}

}
```

This is what I have inside my initialize method thanks to the suggestion in the answer below. The problem is that nothing changes:

```
    @Override
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle rb) {

    plantList.setItems(filteredList);

    //binding filterInput text entries
    filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        String filterText = filterInput.getText();
        if(filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            final String uppercase = filterText.toUpperCase();
            return (plant) -> plant.getName().toUpperCase().contains(uppercase);
        }
    }, filterInput.textProperty()));
```

My goal with this is to filter an ObservableArrayList in real-time, rather than use a button that filters and shows items in a new Scene. I have seen this implemented, and really like the functionality.

Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: You can't modify the `FilteredList` since it's immutable. The purpose of a `FilteredList` is to provide a "view" of another list that is restricted to those elements that match the `Predicate`.  BTW: Checking inside the `Predicate` if the new string is empty or `null` and converting that string to upper case is suboptimal, since it needs to be done only once per text change and not once per `Predicate.test` call. What you're trying to do is almost the same I do in my answer; The difference is that I use a binding to swap the predicate and you do that from a listener.

Comment: So predicates eliminate the need for a listener in this case? I'm brand new to predicates btw.

Comment: There are listeners used. That's just hidden inside the API methods in my answer: `bind` registers a listener, `Bindings.createObjectBinding` registers a listener too, and `FilteredList` listens to changes in the source list. `Predicate` is just a functional interface that provides a method that gets a single argument and returns `boolean`. It's often used to make a decision based on the input. What the `FilteredList` does is quite similar to what [`filter` does to a `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/#pipelines), in case you're more familiar with that.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with those....yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to learn new ways introduced to newer versions of JavaFX. I thought about what I actually wanted to do, wrote it out on paper, and wrote it to the best of my ability/current knowledge.

Here is the working code, still with a ChangeListener in the initialize method, and OnAction still removed from FXML file. Now, when I type a character, the respective plant shows up, and shows the original upon hitting backspace.

I sincerely apoligize for not utilizing what you suggested. I'm not experienced enough yet to fully understand predicates and bindings, but I definitely have something to research!

```
     public void filterPlantList(String oldValue, String newValue) {

    ObservableList<Plant> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    if(filterInput == null || (newValue.length() < oldValue.length()) || newValue == null) {
        plantList.setItems(observablePlantList);
    }
    else {
        newValue = newValue.toUpperCase();
        for(Plant plants : plantList.getItems()) {
            String filterText = plants.getName();
            if(filterText.toUpperCase().contains(newValue)) {
                filteredList.add(plants);
            }
        }
        plantList.setItems(filteredList);
    }
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //add Listener to filterInput TextField
    filterInput.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            filterPlantList((String) oldValue, (String) newValue);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What's wrong with your code:

- you register the listener in the `onAction` event handler of the `TextField` instead of the [`Initializable.initialize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-) method of the controller. This means the listener will be registered when the `Action` event happens (by default when you hit `ENTER`) and a new one will be registered **every time** the `Action` event happens.
- You assign `filterItems` to the `items` property of your `ListView`, but if the text gets shorter, you don't assign a new value before filtering again. That means `plantList.getItems()` (the list you iterate over) can be the same list as the one you add items to => `ConcurrentModificationException`.
- you never clear the filtered list

#### A more elegant way

Use [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html). It's a class that is designed to do the filtering for you.

```
@FXML
private ListView<Plant> plantList;
@FXML
private TextField filterInput;

ObservableList<Plant> observablePlantList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<Plant> filterItems = new FilteredList<>(observablePlantList);

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    plantList.setItems(filterItems);
    
    // bind predicate to text filterInput text
    filterItems.predicateProperty().bind(javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        String text = filterInput.getText();
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            final String uppercase = text.toUpperCase();
            return (plant) -> plant.getName().toUpperCase().contains(uppercase);
        }
    }, filterInput.textProperty()));
}
```

Of course you remove the `onAction` attribute from the `TextField` in the fxml file in this case.

Comment: I marked this as an acceptable answer, but I am not at home to test it. I understand what I did wrong, so I believe it will work once I try it. Thanks for helping me understand how this works.

Comment: Now that I've had time to sit down and look at this, I'm not seeing where you put the listener. It looks as if you have everything inside the initialize method. Is there no longer the filter or search method? Because in my listener I called search((String) oldPlant, (String) newPlant);

Comment: @csheridan: Now that I look more closely your `search` method seems even more odd...(Especially `break;`)The question says that you want to find elements that contain the `TextField`'s text as substring in the name.I bound the predicate that filters the list to the value that is created by the `Callable`(first parameter of `createObjectBinding`) and which depends on the text in the `TextField`;if the text in `filterInput` changes, the `FilteredList`'s predicate is updated to a new predicate that limits the elements to those elements of the original list containing the the new text in the name.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting the list to show only plants that match my string, and filter to a more exact match with the more characters that are typed. Like, if I have a Daisy, Rose, Violet, and Dandelion, and type "D", it will show Daisy and Dandelion. If I add an "a", it will still show those two. Then, if I type "n" it will only show Dandelion. It needs to do the reverse as I press backspace until the original list is shown when the field is empty.

Comment: If I don't get any answers, what do I do, ask the question again in hopes of someone seeing it?

Comment: Edited post to show an update of what is occurring now.

Comment: I almost want you to see the entire program because what you have above does nothing. I removed my listener, and added everything shown above to the initialize method only. At least it doesn't crash, because that's all I was getting before.